Why does MySQL FLOAT insertion throw error even though value to be inserted follows the maximum digits allowed?
Consider the following table
CREATE TABLE float_test (
value FLOAT(3, 2)
);

According to my knowledge, I can insert decimal numbers into this table's value column as long as the number has a total of 3 digits, including digits after decimal point.
By that logic the following query works as expected:
INSERT INTO float_test values(1.11);

However, the below query, which tries to insert a decimal number also with 3 total digits, does not work.
INSERT INTO float_test values(11.1);

Error thrown: ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'value' at row 1
Why does this happen?

(3, 2) means 3 digits, 2 of them after the decimal point, so only 1 before the decimal point. It doesn't mean 3 digits, at most 2 of them after the decimal point.

Thank you, I get it now. I do have 1 more doubt and hope you will clear it, when you do not mention scale and precision for FLOAT, it defaults to FLOAT(10, 2), right? (according to my textbook). Now if I try inserting a value like 11111111.23 and display it using SELECT, the value becomes 11111100. How does this make sense?

@rpicoder floats are stored inaccurately by design.  you almost always want to use DECIMAL instead

Use DOUBLE instead of FLOAT. FLOAT doesn't have enough precision to hold  10 digits.

double is still stored inaccurately; do use decimal unless you really know you need double.

and your textbook is wrong.  it appears the default is float(12) (with decimals unspecified).  but as of mysql 8, use of number of digits or decimals at all is deprecated; expect them to be no longer supported in a future release.

Does that apply to float and double only or even decimal? According to my textbook which I no longer trust, decimal  NEEDS to have number of digits and decimals mentioned, however, when I tried, it works without throwing any error but the decimal is completely ignored.

@rpicoder It only applies to the floating point types. The whole point of DECIMAL is to allow you to specify the number of digits precisely (e.g. for monetary amounts). You can easily read the documentation to see which ones are deprecated.

float/double/integer types but not decimal. FLOAT(M,D)and DOUBLE(M,D) are nonstandard MySQL extensions; and are deprecated. You should expect support for these variants to be removed in a future version of MySQL The ZEROFILL attribute is deprecated for numeric data types, as is the display width attribute for integer data types. You should expect support for ZEROFILL and display widths for integer data types to be removed in a future version of MySQL.
